# Entity Framework query slow, but same SQL in SqlQuery is fast

Tags: performance, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm seeing some really strange perf related to a very simple query using Entity Framework Code-First with .NET framework version 4. The LINQ2Entities query looks like this:

```
 context.MyTables.Where(m => m.SomeStringProp == stringVar);
```

This takes over 3000 milliseconds to execute. The generated SQL looks very simple:

```
 SELECT [Extent1].[ID], [Extent1].[SomeStringProp], [Extent1].[SomeOtherProp],
 ...
 FROM [MyTable] as [Extent1]
 WHERE [Extent1].[SomeStringProp] = '1234567890'
```

This query runs almost instantaneously when run through Management Studio. When I change the C# code to use the SqlQuery function, it runs in 5-10 milliseconds:

```
 context.MyTables.SqlQuery("SELECT [Extent1].[ID] ... WHERE [Extent1].[SomeStringProp] = @param", stringVar);
```

So, exact same SQL, the resulting entities are change-tracked in both cases, but wild perf difference between the two. What gives?

Comment: I expect you're seeing initialization delays - probably view compilation. See MSDN: [`Performance Considerations for Entity Framework 5`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx)

Comment: I've tried pre-generating views, and it doesn't seem to help. Also, ran another EF query before the slow one to rule out initialization stuff. New query ran quickly, the slow one still ran slowly, even though context warm-up happened during the first query.

Comment: @marc_s - No, SqlQuery will return a fully-materialized and change-tracked entity instance. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.sqlquery(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: Is the generated SQL for your EF query actually inlining the parameter value, or using a parameter? This shouldn't affect query speed for an individual query, but could cause queryplan bloat in the server over time.

Comment: Have you tried running the same query twice/multiple times? How long did it take when running the second time? Have you tried this on .NET Framework 4.5 - there are some EF related perf improvements in .NET Framework 4.5 that could help.

Comment: @JimWooley - No, EF is inlining the string value. I suppose I could try hard-coding it into my SqlQuery call to see if I get similar (bad) perf, but like you said, I doubt that's it.

Comment: EF detects if the variable is a constant or user entered and inlines or parameterizes it appropriately. I doubt that's the issue with your query, but try making it a changeable variable and retesting.

Comment: @Kiquenet - There's really not much more source code to show other than what's in the question and in the answer.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Found it. It turns out it's an issue of SQL data types. The `SomeStringProp` column in the database was a varchar, but EF assumes that .NET string types are nvarchars. The resulting translation process during the query for the DB to do the comparison is what takes a long time. I think EF Prof was leading me astray a bit here, a more accurate representation of the query being run would be the following:

```
 SELECT [Extent1].[ID], [Extent1].[SomeStringProp], [Extent1].[SomeOtherProp],
 ...
 FROM [MyTable] as [Extent1]
 WHERE [Extent1].[SomeStringProp] = N'1234567890'
```

So the resulting fix is to annotate the code-first model, indicating the correct SQL data type:

```
public class MyTable
{
    ...

    [Column(TypeName="varchar")]
    public string SomeStringProp { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 62):

The reason of slowing down my EF queries was comparing not nullable scalars with nullable scalars:

```
long? userId = 10; // nullable scalar

db.Table<Document>().Where(x => x.User.Id == userId).ToList() // or userId.Value
                                ^^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^
                                Type: long   Type: long?
```

That query took 35 seconds. But a tiny refactoring like the following:

```
long? userId = 10;
long userIdValue = userId.Value;

db.Table<Document>().Where(x => x.User.Id == userIdValue).ToList()
                                ^^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^^
                                Type: long   Type: long
```

gives incredible results: it took only 50ms to complete. It looks like a bug in EF.

Comment: This is so weird

Comment: OMG. This can apparently also happen when using interfaces IUserId.Id was causing the problem with me, but first mapping Id to an integer works... do I have to check now all queries in my 100.000 lines application?

Comment: has this bug been reported? It's still in the latest version 6.2.0

Comment: The same issue is also in EF Core. Thanks for finding this!

Comment: One other suggestion is to process the variable before putting into LINQ expression. Otherwise the generated sql will be much longer and slower. I experienced when having Trim() and ToLower() inside LINQ expression that bugs me up.

Comment: This just solved a problem I was having

Answer (score 12):

If you're using the fluent mapping, you can use `IsUnicode(false)` as part of the configuration to get the same effect -

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx#1.9

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696416%28v=vs.103%29.aspx

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem (the query is fast when executed from SQL manager) but when executed from EF the timeout expires.

Turns out that the entity (which was was created from the view) had wrong entity keys. So the entity had duplicate rows with the same keys, and I guess it had to do grouping on the background.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem as well. It turns out the culprit in my case was SQL-Server [parameter sniffing](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/).

The first clue that my problem was in fact due to parameter sniffing was that running the query with "set arithabort off" or "set arithabort on" yielded drastically different execution times in Management Studio. This is because ADO.NET by default uses "set arithabort off" and Management Studio defaults to "set arithabort on". The query plan cache keeps different plans depending on this parameter.

I disabled query plan caching for the query, with the solution you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47327803/540832).

Answer (score 3):

I also came across this with a complex ef query.
One fix for me which reduced a 6 second ef query to the sub second sql query it generated was to turn off lazy loading.

To find this setting (ef 6) go to the .edmx file and look in the Properties -> Code generation -> Lazy Loading Enabled. Set to false.

Massive improvement in performance for me.

Comment: That's cool, but has nothing to do with the posters question.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very strange EF bug that happened to me and is one more reason this could go south.

I had the following line of code:

`var fvQuery = db.DataValues.Where(x => x.DataId == dataId && x.Scope == scope && x.Start <= endTime && startTime <= x.End)`

Note that the last part of the Where clause has the terms reversed, with the value being compared against on the left side!

This almost always worked, then bugged out in rare circumstances, with the query taking several minutes in Entity Framework before it was sent to the DB, if at all.

The fix:

`var fvQuery = db.DataValues.Where(x => x.DataId == dataId && x.Scope == scope && x.Start <= endTime && x.End >= startTime)`

Swapping the order of the terms in the last part of the WHERE clause seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was a deadlock cause by a calling method that forgot to `await` my async method. The `query.ToArrayAsync()` was executed but never returned to the caller thread.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar experience unsolvable with other replies in here and went for the [direct SQL query outside the EF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21709305/how-to-directly-execute-sql-query-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me again in a similar part of the code I was working on (see my other answer here for how I solved it the first time).

This time, the culprit was the query optimizer forgetting to use an index. When running the query in most cases, or under SSMS, the correct indexes would be used. Only occasionally under specific circumstances would it fail.

When I used an SQL profiler and set it to show execution plans, it showed that in the long-running queries, the query optimizer was ignoring the index that had been set and doing a table scan instead (of 6 million+ rows!), drastically increasing the run time.

The fix for this was to turn the query into a table-valued function with an index hint, forcing the correct index, and call that function from within EF. This resolved the problem, though it's somewhat of a drastic solution. I don't know why the query optimizer decided to ignore the index, but this guarantees it will not in the future.